# From a list of flask BaseQuery objects, how can I find the item with a specific ID?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

(Flask / Jinja2 / SQLAlchemy)

I have a page where different users can post comments to, and I'm trying to get the user's name on their comments. The problem is that the comments table uses a foreign key in the "author" column, so when I try to call the comment's author using `{{ comment.author }}`, I get the user's ID instead.

To get all the comments on the page, I'm using the following in **views.py**:

```
# ...
all_comments = Comments.query.filter_by(page = this_page.id)
return render_template('page.html', all_comments = all_comments)
# ...
```

On the jinja template, I'm using the following to display all the comments:

```
{% for comment in all_comments %}
    {{ comment.author }}:
    {{ comment.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output I'm getting is something like `1: my comment`, instead of `name: my comment`.

My initial solution is to pass along a `commenters` variable containing a BaseQuery object with all the people who posted on the page, and then trying to call the correct commenter by passing in the user id, `{{ commenters[post.author] }}`. Unfortunately, this can only return the n-th commenter instead of the commenter with the specific ID I wanted.

How do I get an object from the BaseQuery that has a specific ID in the jinja template? I welcome alternative solutions, but I'd also like a solution to this specific scenario please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to query the Users table for each item in `all_comments`, and then assign the user's name to the entry without committing the change in **views.py**:

```
# ...
for entry in all_comments:
    entry.author = Users.query.get(entry.author).name
# ...
```

This allowed me to get the author's name when calling `{{ comment.author }}`. However, this just looks wrong for some reason. Alternatives appreciated!